# Backing up MySQL to UbutuOne

Tags: ubuntu-one, mysql

I use mysql as a backend for my xbmc, I also have a ubuntu one account.

What is the best way to regularly back up the database to ubuntu one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `mysql-admin` tools to connect and create scheduled backups of your databases to any location you desire, including your Ubuntu One folder. You can install `mysql-admin` through Terminal using `sudo apt-get install mysql-admin` or through a package manager like Synaptic.

The `mysql-admin` tools have been deprecated and replaced by Oracle with MySQL Workbench which does not offer built-in backup options, but the older tools still function with current MySQL databases.

I'm performing essentially what you are trying to achieve using `mysql-admin`, performing regular backups of my MySQL databases to GoogleDrive, and it works perfectly.